# How to extract specific value from string in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have column with values like this:

```
$30K - $50K
```

How to extract lower limit? Is it possible do it in SQL query without writing own function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is possible ..

if you want to extract only lower limit value then you can use following query while selecting columns from your table  --

```
 Mid(<your field name >,2,Instr (<your field name >, "K")-1)
```

else if you want to select with special character then you can use following statement -

```
 Mid(<your field name >,1,Instr (<your field name >, "K"))
```

please try it.. I don't have MS-access in my machine else I would have tested this before posting ..